# Sharepoint workflow issue for users

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

I have 5 users in with full control over the site,But only when I create an item in the list,workflow will be initiated,what could be the solution to solve this issue?

Comment: Could you please provide more information? Any error messages, which version of SharePoint, ...?

Comment: Workflow automatically starts when an item is created,In my site I have 5 user with full control,They are able to add item,but workflow is not happening,but When I create an item in the list,Workflow is happening perfectly fine.I ma using 2013 SP Designer

Comment: could it be that you set yourself as the initiator of the workflow?

Answer (score 1):

Open SharePoint Designer and Connect to your site. Click on Workflows from the left navigation, and click on your workflow. Workflow information page will open. In the "Settings" area in the right pane, uncheck the "Automatically update the workflow status to the current stage name". This will fix the problem. If that box is checked the workflow cannot be run by the System Account.

I found my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17222287/sharepoint-2013-workflow-not-firing-when-document-checked-in-but-works-if-checke).